# How to add add multiple extended JPanels into one JFrame in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I want two images from two different classes that extend JPanel to be side by side.

The problem that I'm having is that the two JPanels should be inside the JFrame but when I do framename.add(panel) it replaces the other one instead of adding two of them side by side.

I have tried adding flowlayout and other layouts inside the main class, but none of the images showed up.

**So my question is**, if I have two classes that extend Jpanel, how do i add those two panels inside a Jframe so that they'll be side by side (next to each other) without replacing the other panel?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: If I extend JFrame to a class, does that class automatically become a JPanel itself? I know what extends means, but I'm not sure how it works in regards to a Jframe.

**Main.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main
{       
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();           

        Panel1 s = new Panel1(); //picture 1
        Panel2 n = new Panel2(); //picture 2

        frame.add(n);
        frame.add(s); //here is the problem, it replaces the previous panel

        f.setSize(200,100);
        f.setLocation(0,400);                    
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

**Panel1.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class image2 extends JPanel 
    {
        ImageIcon anotherIcon;

        public image2() //constructor
            {                               
                 URL imageURL = Panel1.class.getResource("images/puppy.png");            
                 anotherIcon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
            }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);                
                anotherIcon.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);                           
            }       
    }
```

**Panel2.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Panel2 extends JPanel 
    {
        ImageIcon anotherIcon2;

        public Panel2() //constructor
            {                               
                 URL imageURL = Panel2.class.getResource("images/puppy2.png");           
                 anotherIcon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
            }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);                
                anotherIcon2.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);                          
            }       
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) has implemented [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) in the API
- only one [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) can be placed to the one [of 5th. areas in BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

> I want two images from two different classes that extend JPanel to be
>   side by side.

- change [built_in LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to the [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

or

- use [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) with [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) in the case that there aren't any JComponent added to [JPanels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)

Answer (score 1):

The JFrame's default layout manager is BorderLayout. Try changing it to use something like GridLayout instead

Take a look at [A visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more ideas

Answer (score 0):

Try `frame.getContentPane().add(...)`?

And set the layout **of the contentpane** to FlowLayout (or other)

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("This is a test");
f.setSize(400, 150);
Container content = f.getContentPane();
content.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
content.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
content.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I tried your code that you added in there, neither panel shows up when i run the program :x.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the panels directly to the JFrame, you have to adds the panels in the contentPane.

It's also recomended create a panel to be the contentPane `frame.setContentPane(myPanel);`
and configure it with some layout (BorderLayout, GridBagLayout, whatever...)

Answer (score 0):

In frame set FlowLayout()

frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

Answer (score 0):

I corrected both Panel1.java and Panel2.java of minor mistakes and added an example of how you'd place them side by side using `GridBagLayout`/`GridBagConstraints` combo:

Main.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            Panel1 s = new Panel1(); //picture 1

            Panel2 n = new Panel2(); //picture 2

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            frame.add(n, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            frame.add(s, gbc); //here is the problem, it replaces the previous panel

            frame.setSize(200,100);
            frame.setLocation(0,400);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       }
    }
```

Panel1.java

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class Panel1 extends JPanel {
        ImageIcon anotherIcon;

        public Panel1 ( ) {
            URL imageURL = Panel1.class.getResource("images/puppy.png");
            anotherIcon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            anotherIcon.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Panel2.java

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class Panel2 extends JPanel {
        ImageIcon anotherIcon;

        public Panel2 ( ) {
            URL imageURL = Panel2.class.getResource("images/puppy2.png");
            anotherIcon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            anotherIcon.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

The general idea for your code was not wrong, just that the panels were placed one on top of the other, causing one to hide the other....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Set Layout of your Frame as:
**setLayout(null)**
and then can add Bounds to your panel
ie. **setBounds()**
and then add these panels to frame